# (Auth) Problem with signInWithPopup on Chrome Extension

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

When I try to implement the signInWithPopup I get a Refused to load the script error

```
const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
  try {
    // Attach the auth object to the provider
    googleProvider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: 'select_account' });
    const result = await signInWithPopup(auth, googleProvider);
    const { user } = result;
    console.log(user);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

signInWithGoogle()
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem here?
Just to let you know that in manifest json v3 if you have firebase backend its not possible to directly call google signing there are workaround to use identity and do it. I am working on the same and trying to figure it out.

Here is example code I am using for it.

```
const getGoogleAuthCredential = () => {
  return new Promise<ReturnType<typeof GoogleAuthProvider.credential>>((resolve, reject) => {
    if (typeof chrome !== 'undefined' && chrome.identity) {
      chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: true }, (token: any) => {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
          console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
          reject(chrome.runtime.lastError);
        }
        console.log({ token });
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential("YOUR_KEY", token);
        console.log({ credential })
        resolve(credential);
      });
    } else {
      // Handle the case when the `chrome` object is not available
      reject(new Error('Chrome extension environment is required.'));
    }
  });
};


export const googleAuthHandler = async () => {
  try {
    let credential;
    // Check if running in Chrome extension environment
    if (window.location.origin.includes("chrome-extension")) {
      credential = await getGoogleAuthCredential();
    } else {
      // Use regular GoogleAuthProvider for non-extension environments
      const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
      await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
      return;
    }
    console.log({ credential })
    const result = await signInWithPopup(auth, credential);
    return result.user;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    triggerMessage("Error signing in with Google. Please try again.", "error")
    return null;
  }
};
```

we can connect on twitter if you have more doubts on this
@pratikk_tiwari